# Creating private Vc discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, channel

I am trying to create a private vc for a function i am trying to make. it makes the vc with the permissions i want it to make, but then it gives an error after it made it and i cannot put any code behind it.
This is the code:

```
guild = ctx.author.guild
players_role = await guild.create_role(name=f"Players {game_id}")
for i in all_players:
    print(all_players)
    print(i)
    i = guild.get_member(int(i[1]))
    await i.add_roles(players_role)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        players_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    }
    players_vc = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Game: {game_id}", overwrites=overwrites)

    await players_vc.edit(position=len(ctx.guild.voice_channels))
    print("edited position")
```

What I am trying to do is edit the vc I created so that it gets pulled to the bottom, but it doesnt do this, because it gives an error in the previous line. I tried putting the `players_vc = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"Game: {game_id}", overwrites=overwrites)` in `try:` and `except:` but I need the variable to edit the position. here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Thijs coding map\TeaBot\TeaBot.py", line 889, in vc_test
    test_vc = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"test vc", overwrites=overwrites)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 888, in create_voice_channel
    channel = VoiceChannel(state=self._state, guild=self, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 553, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 584, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_new'
```

for troubleshooting, you can use this code:

```
@client.command()
async def vc_test(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = ctx.author
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    }
    test_vc = await guild.create_voice_channel(f"test vc", overwrites=overwrites)

    await test_vc.edit(position=len(guild.voice_channels))
    print("edited position")
```

I couldn't find this issue elsewhere
all help is appreciated

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
venv\lib\site-package\discord\abc.py
```

open and find

`_Overwrites = namedtuple('_Overwrites', 'id allow deny type')`

and replace

```
class _Overwrites:
    __slots__ = ('id', 'allow', 'deny', 'type')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.id = kwargs.pop('id')
        self.allow = kwargs.pop('allow', 0)
        self.deny = kwargs.pop('deny', 0)
        self.type = kwargs.pop('type')

    def _asdict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'allow': self.allow,
            'deny': self.deny,
            'type': self.type,
        }
```

You can look [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/0bc15fa130b8f01fe2d67446a2184d474b0d0ba7)